# Hibernate — почему не работает кэш первого уровня?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Из [статьи на хабре](https://habr.com/post/135176/):
Кеш первого уровня всегда привязан к объекту сессии. Hibernate всегда по умолчанию использует этот кеш и его нельзя отключить.

Мой код, проверка работы кэша.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "okof")
public class Okof {
    @Id
    protected String code;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public Okof() {
    }
  ...
}

@Repository
public class JpaOkofRepositoryImpl implements OkofRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<Okof> getOkofList() {
        Okof o = em.find(Okof.class, "330.13.92.2");
        System.out.println(o.getCode());
        o = em.find(Okof.class, "330.13.92.2");
        System.out.println(o.getCode());
        // return em.createNamedQuery(Okof.ALL_SORTED, Okof.class).getResultList();
        return null;
    }
  ...
}
```

Тестируем:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try (GenericXmlApplicationContext appCtx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext()) {
    appCtx.load("spring/spring-app.xml", "spring/spring-db.xml");
    appCtx.refresh();

    OkofRepository repository = appCtx.getBean(OkofRepository.class);
    repository.getOkofList();
  }
}
```

В консоле видим:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        okof0_.code as code1_1_0_,
        okof0_.name as name2_1_0_,
        okof0_.parent_code as parent_c3_1_0_ 
    from
        okof okof0_ 
    where
        okof0_.code=?
330.13.92.2
Hibernate: 
    select
        okof0_.code as code1_1_0_,
        okof0_.name as name2_1_0_,
        okof0_.parent_code as parent_c3_1_0_ 
    from
        okof okof0_ 
    where
        okof0_.code=?
330.13.92.2
```

Почему запрос уходит в базу два раза? Получается что кэш почему-то не отрабатывает.

Comment: Ваш метод не помечен как Transactional, соответственно хайбернейт не менеджит ваши энтити.

Comment: О как. С Transactional сработало. То есть если метод не помечен Transactional, то при вызове em.persist(...) переданная сущность не перейдет в состояние «управляемая» (managed) и будет просто "висеть в воздухе" ?

Comment: Ну и сразу еще вопрос, если в методе вместо Okof o = em.find(Okof.class, "330.13.92.2"); написать List<Okof> l1 = em.createQuery("SELECT o FROM Okof o ORDER BY o.code").getResultList(); два раза, то даже при Transactional  все равно запрос уходит два раза. Получается, em.createQuery не кэшируется?

Comment: Кинется эксепшен при персисте, если нет Transactional.  А касательно листа,  к сожалению, не помню если хайб менеджит лист.

Comment: Чтобы проверить используется ли кеш первого уровня - > сделайте квери. Измените состояние объекта. Если объект в кеше, значит хайбернейт его отслеживает, затем хайб сам сделает квери и поменяет запись в базе.